# How to connect my host name to my proxy server using apache

Tags: networking, server, apache2, proxy, reverse-proxy

Im using apache configured as a proxy server to connect hostnames linked to my external static IP address to ports on my internal server.

My router is configured to point to my server via port 80 using port forwarding.

My apache configuration is set to point my.hostname.com to 192.168.server.ip:8081 which hosts a web server.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

   ServerName myproxy.net
   ServerAlias www.myproxy.net

   ProxyPreserveHost on
   ProxyPass / http://192.168.server.ip:8080/


</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>

   ServerName my.hostname.com
   ServerAlias www.my.hostname.com  

   ProxyPreserveHost on
   ProxyPass / http://192.168.server.ip:8081/


</VirtualHost>
```

After this I had done a `service apache2 reload`

When I enter `my.hostname.com/test.php` in my browser (test.php is a file in my document root directory in a docker container that port 8081 points to) I get a 503 error.

But if I enter `http://192.168.server.ip:8081/test.php` into my browser I get the webpage I'm trying to reach.

Am I configuring apache wrong? or is there perhaps something I am missing?

Please note: `192.168.server.ip` is not my external ip address its my local ip address to my server.

Comment: what does `host my.hostname.com` tell you?

Comment: it gives me a 503 error

Comment: `host my.hostname.com` is a shell command, that you need to type into a shell.

Comment: oh ok one moment

Comment: its giving me a "bash: host: command not found"

Comment: do i need to install a package?

Comment: You can search for file names in packages like this: https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=artful&arch=any&mode=exactfilename&searchon=contents&keywords=host. But never mind - you can also do a `ping -c 1 my.hostname.com` that should answer my question about whether your browser can actually resolve the name `my.hostname.com`, which it needs to, in order to access your website.

Comment: 1 packets transmitted, 1 received, 0% packet loss, time 0ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.368/0.368/0.368/0.000 ms

Comment: The point here is: does it ping to `192.168.server.ip`?

Comment: One more thing: in your browser open the developper tools or such, select the network stack, and have a look what is transmitted between the browser and the server.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/69464/discussion-between-jermayne-williams-and-tomas-pospisek).