# How to make my site live

Tags: server, apache2

I created all my php files and wants to put this to the `public_html` file on Linode (Ubuntu16.04LTS). How can i make my site live?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First make sure you made a directory `/var/www/html/MyDomain.com/public_html` to house all your file as wanted.

> **NOTE: REPLACE MyDomain.com with your domain name as wanted**

Assuming that you've setup the full LAMP on your server, here's what you need to do. Create a `.conf` file located at `/etc/apache2/sites-available/MyDomain.com.conf`.

> **NOTE: REPLACE MyDomain.com with your domain name as wanted**

Then type command `nano /etc/apache2/sites-available/MyDomain.com.conf` to edit the file and paste this codes to it:

```
# domain: MyDomain.com
# public: /var/www/html/MyDomain.com/public_html

<VirtualHost *:80>
  # Admin email, Server Name (domain name), and any aliases
  ServerAdmin webmaster@MyDomain.com
  ServerName  MyDomain.com
  ServerAlias www.MyDomain.com

  # Index file and Document Root (where the public files are located)
  DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
  DocumentRoot /var/www/html/MyDomain.com/public_html
  # Log file locations
  LogLevel warn
  ErrorLog  /var/www/html/MyDomain.com/log/error.log
  CustomLog /var/www/html/MyDomain.com/log/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

> **This is the default .conf file provided by Linode**

Then type the command `a2dissite *default` to remove or disable the default apache2 and then type `a2ensite MyDomain.com.conf` to enable the site. Also, type `service apache2 reload` to make the site live.

> **AGAIN, TAKE NOTE TO REPLACE MyDomain.com with your domain**

You might want to add the DNS zones to linode and add a slave IP.

Step 1:
Login to Linode and Click `DNS Manager` and click `add a domain zone`. Then Provide these details:

[Guide Photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pDeQi.png)

Step 2:
Go to `Linodes>YourLinode###>Remote Access` and click `reverse DNS`. In then put your domain there and click `Look up`

Comment: Tell me if anything goes wrong

Comment: Your welcome! @TrustFinancial

Comment: @codycortez Do you mind looking at this question for me?
https://askubuntu.com/questions/981604/how-to-connect-my-host-name-to-my-proxy-server-using-apache